# printing columns from all queries into one

Tags: sql

i have 2 groupby queries,each counts rows for each compnay_id, both grouped by company_id.
i need to output one query that will print column qty1, qty2, company_id
union doesnt work for me:

```
select count(*) as qty1
from T_MISSION
where datepart(month, [mdatetime])=12
group by  company_id

union all

select count(*) as qty2
from T_CUSTSK
where datepart(month, [sdate])=12
group by  company_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
select sum(qty1), sum(qty2), company_id
from
(
 select count(*) as qty1, 0 as qty2, company_id
 from T_MISSION
 where datepart(month, [mdatetime])=12
 group by  company_id

 union all

 select 0 as qty1, count(*) as qty2, company_id
 from T_CUSTSK
 where datepart(month, [sdate])=12
 group by  company_id
) as combined
group by company_id
```

The idea: Use a separate column for each value. Set all other columns to `0` per each data collection so they do not mix up strangely. Finally sum them all up (per customer) so there is exactly one value per column and customer, as all others are `0` by definition.

This little trick allows for mixing otherwise unrelated data.

Comment: why you used sum() function  ?

Comment: see my explanation in the answer. Sum() is actually just a trick to combine the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a expert in SQL but would LEFT JOIN work for you?
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: no because there are 2 counts from each query with group by that i assume that needs to be grouped by on all the final table because both queries grouped by same company_id